# visible word in a wordwrap element

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, mootools, yui

in a long wordwrap element, is there any way to detect the left-top-most visible word?

using span around each word or bunch of words is not really a good option as the text will be too long and dynamically loaded to be a good performance, but i may consider this is nothing else appears.

sample code (play with it http://jsfiddle.net/8utcp/2/ ):

```
<style> #test { height: 100px; width: 150px; overflow: auto; } </style>

<div id=test> with lots of text </div>

<script> $("#test").scrollTop(50); // simulate user scroll </script>
```

Now you have this in the test div:

[image: scrolled text with word wrap]

How do I figure out that the First visible word is "Adpiscing"?

answers can use any framework. be based around javascript or css. even solutions that do not work on all browsers are welcome as they can be a good starting point. I simply can't find anything about this problem.

More clarification.
If I have a long text, and i open it in the browser and scroll down, and later i open it in another device, with different screen size, or even in the same browser, but with 10x more zoom. Which property/logic would ensure that the first visible word matches all the time.<

Comment: When you say "word" do you mean a text in a text-node?

Comment: What do you mean with "left-top-most visible word"?

Comment: You need the first word of a phrase?

Comment: Yes @gdoron. and for javascript_is_future, if would be the first word in the screen at the top-left corner. for this block of text, it would be "Yes"

Comment: @DavidRodrigues Word should suffice.

Comment: So you need get the most top-left text-node on the screen?

Comment: @DavidRodrigues not NODE, but part of the content of the node. I know most of the screen will be used by ONE node with lots of text, and the screen will be scrolled somewhere. Currently i'm using a percentage of the total node height versus the amount scrolled and porting it across devices screen sizes. but it's not very precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is, no, you can't get positions of words. the long answer is, you can do what you want to do but it's hacky.

what I can think of is this:

- split based upon whitespace
- walk the word tokens and inject a span element with, say--position absolute before and after the word, you can even st the innerHTML to orig `wordsArray.join(" <span></span>")` so your spaces/words become measurable or you can wrap every word in a span instead.
- you can get the offsets of the spans from parent now, giving you rough coords for each word
- work out - based upon scroll - which one is likely the first visible.
- get rid of the spans.

Comment: this is the brute force i was trying to avoid :) have one implementation using this but one span per phrase. and it's too slugish. one per paragraph is acceptable, but then i have roughly the same precision than using percentages hacks, which is instantaneous.